# consume KeyEvent.VK_ENTER from JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing

I have an application with certain JComponents (e.g JPanels) that are able to handle KeyEvent.VK_ENTER with the help of an InputMap / ActionMap.

This works well, with one exception: If I have an JFileChooser to select a file AND I finish this selection with the  from keyboard, this key-event is passed to the next active JPanel of my application. The file selection works well, but the event of the pressed/released/typed enter is forwarded, cause on this panel an action that is related to a KeyEvent.VK_ENTER on that panel is performed! If I finish the JFileChooser via the mouse, it works as expected and nothing is done on the next active JPanel.

How can I consume such a KeyEvent at the JFileChooser? I tried to establish a KeyBinding at the class that covers the JFileChooser, but this works not. I add the code for this part here:

```
public myClass(String theirDir){
    fc = new FileChooser(theirDir);
    this.bindKeyToAction(fc, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, true);
}// end constructor()

private bindKeyToAction(JComponent theirComp, KeyStroke theirStroke){
    InputMap localInput = theirComp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    localInput.put(theirStroke, theirStroke,.getKeyChar());

    theirComp.getActionMap().put(theirStroke.getKeyChar(), this.generateAction(new String("theCommand");
}// end bindKeyToAction

private Action generateAction(String theirID){
    final String localID = theirID;

    return new AbstractAction(theirID){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent theirEve){
           do something....
        }
    };
}// end generateAction()

...
}// end myClass
```

But it never reaches "do something..."?!?

Comment: I don't think the problem is so much with the file chooser but the root pane of the dialog begin used by the file chooser

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer! But I can't see any root pane, as the JFileChooser is a private att within the class. And it's not added to any container. I just use it via the showOpenDialog() or the showSaveDialog(). If I call fc.getRootPane(), I get a null. Or do you mean the contentPane?